# Como puedo quitar el color azul que traen un option! Ayuda!

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hola Amigos buenas tardes, lo que pasa es que quiero eliminar el color azul por defecto en un comboBox al momento de pasar sobre las opciones, ya probe con el hover, pero no tuve exito este es la pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
option:hover
{
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
 
    /*        color: #F4F4F4;*/
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(../img/palomita.png )   no-repeat 100%;

}
```

```html
             <select class="selectArrow" name="AAS" class="Caja_txt_246" id="AAS" tabindex="9">
                                <option selected="selected" value="0">0 %</option>
                                <option value="5">5 %</option>
                                <option value="10">10 %</option>
                                <option value="15">15 %</option>
                                <option value="20">20 %</option>
                            </select>
```

Ya volvi a editar la pregunta con el codigo ejecutando, (Lo principal es desaparecer el color azul, ya sea jquery, js o css)

Espero y me puedan ayudar, saludos cordiales XDD

Comment: Te recomiendo que coloques el código que tienes hasta el momento para poder ayudarte de una forma mas fácil, te recomiendo que leas esto para formular una pregunta correcta https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Como cambiar color en un option cuando se posiciona sobre el elemento, dejar la palomita?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/121069/como-cambiar-color-en-un-option-cuando-se-posiciona-sobre-el-elemento-dejar-la)

Comment: Es correcto, en el link que mando Kevin fue una pregunta que hice ayer por la noche XDD

Comment: @JUANJOSEBUSTAMANTESOLIS por que preguntas dos veces lo mismo ? deberías de dejar únicamente una pregunta, es importante que leas [ask] para que puedas redactar preguntas que sean bien recibidas en la comunidad, saludos !

Comment: Una disculpa por eso :( lo que pasa es que la otra pregunta no hubo respuesta y pense que a lo mejor ya nadie estaba por lo tarde que era XDD

Comment: @JUANJOSEBUSTAMANTESOLIS podrías eliminar la pregunta anterior y dejar esta, editarla y agregar ordenadamente tu código y si es posible hacer un ejemplo que se pueda ejecutar desde el snippet seria genial, eso ayudará a que las personas de la comunidad te puedan ofrecer muy buenas respuesta...una buena pregunta obtiene buenas respuestas

Comment: Hola de nuevo, ya volvi a editar la pregunta. :)

Comment: En el pantallazo que has proporcionado pareciera que usaras una librería, por que no la importas al snippet ?

Answer (score 1):

Ese color "Hover" en las opciones de un control Select es propio de cada navegador, así que no es posible cambiarlo directamente en un control de ese tipo.

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar alguna librería de Jquery que simule el Select:

```
<select id="select-beast">
     <option value="3" selected="selected">Nikola Tesla</option>
</select>

$('#select-beast').selectize({
     create: true,
     sortField: 'text'
});
```

Este es un ejemplo de la librería [Selectize.js](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/)

Comment: Hola, perdon por la demora, voy a revisar el codigo que me pasaste, igual se esta viendo si se va a requerir esta funcionalidad, muchas gracias :)